# span onclick does not work jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a treeview structure created with css and jquery. To expand a node I want the user to click on a `<span>` within the `<li>` (it's an image) and not on the node itself.

So here is my HTML part :

```
<div class="tree">      
<ul>
<li class="parent active"><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent active"><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="parent active"><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a>
          <ul>
             <li class="parent active"><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 3</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a>Level 4</a></li>
                </ul>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the JS part for the clikc event on span (but it doesn't work) :

```
$( '.tree li.parent > span.expand' ).click( function( ) {
    $( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'active' );
    $( this ).parent().children( 'ul' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );
});
```

However, the following code works but by clicking on the `<a>` within the `<li>` :

```
 $( '.tree li.parent > a' ).click( function( ) {
    $( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'active' );
    $( this ).parent().children( 'ul' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );
 });
```

I need to expand the nodes by clicking on the span because when clicking on the node I need to redirect to another page to display its details.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ucy1gjb/) that a created for this question.

So why the click event on span does not work ?

Comment: Just clean your opening and closing tags. I think you did some mess there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with css. Tag a is overlapping your span. Replace padding with margin and everything will start working.

Upd.: Actually - remove `display:block` from your rules for `a` tag
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ucy1gjb/2/

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing `</li>` tag:

```
<div class="tree">      
<ul>
<li class="parent active"><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent active"><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="parent active"><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a>
          <ul>
             <li class="parent active"><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 3</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a>Level 4</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li> <!-----I Was Missing!-->
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="expand"></span><a>Level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right but it doesn't completly resolve the problem. It works for level 2 and 3 but not for level 1.

Comment: This answers your question "So why the click event on span does not work ?"

Comment: @TahaPaksu I've added the missing tag but still have same probelm with node of level 1. So it does not completly answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `padding` use `margin` for this class

```
.tree li.parent > a {
    padding: 0 0 0 28px;
}
```

replace it with :

```
.tree li.parent > a {
    margin: 0 0 0 28px;
}
```

as it is now your `a` tag overlays the `span.expand` so it's not clickable.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7a4zsz6g/)

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS selector you have `.tree li.parent > span.expand`. This selector is wrong for your markup. What this is looking for is

```
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li class="parent">
      <span class="expand"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

That `>` means direct child, which you don't have. Just remove that, and you should be fine.

`$(".tree li.parent span.expand").on('click', function() {});`

**Edit** As it was pointed out to me, I missed the top level `<span class="expand">`. The click event would work for that top level, but wouldn't work on any of the inner ones. I would still recommend changing the CSS selector if you'd like it to click through on all of them.

Comment: I actually think the ">" is ok for OP's html. OP does have `span.expand` immediately under a `li.parent`.

Comment: oh, you're right! I actually didn't see that one hiding over there >_< I'll edit.