# Building span with click event on fly and click event will not trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

After making a call to the server depending on the details that come back I  may or may not build a span statement.

I'm building the statement with

```
'<span class="icon icon-close removeGiftcard js-gift-card-remove js-gc-remove-amount-' + i + ' onclick="removegiftcard();"></span>'
```

and here's the full line:

```
 $(".js-gc-display-amount-" + i).text("-" +
                        checkoutData.GiftCards[i].Amount.toLocaleString("en-GB",
                            { style: "currency", currency: "GBP" })).append('<span class="icon icon-close removeGiftcard js-gift-card-remove js-gc-remove-amount-' + i + ' onclick="removegiftcard();"></span>');
```

If I look using Chrome I can see from the element tab, that all looks ok with my span statement. however, my removegiftcard() function does not fire when I click on the my icon.

Comment: your quotes are wrong... The class is never closed so it uses the onclick opening...

Comment: onclick is not a class, don't include it in `class`. Plus what @epascarello said.

Comment: @epascarello after making your change. in the browser I now see : `<span class="icon icon-close removeGiftcard js-gift-card-remove js-gc-remove-amount-0" onclick="removegiftcard();"></span>` but the function still doesn't fire

Comment: @bilpor with the information provided it is impossible to know why it does not work. I can make educated guesses, but would be better with more info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [span onclick does not work jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708584/span-onclick-does-not-work-jquery)

Comment: @bilpor if you have updated the logic, please update your question to reflect your changes.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments, your statement should be:

```
'<span class="icon icon-close removeGiftcard js-gift-card-remove js-gc-remove-amount-' + i + '"></span>'
```

And the code:

```
$(".js-gc-display-amount-" + i).text("-" + checkoutData.GiftCards[i].Amount.toLocaleString("en-GB", { style: "currency", currency: "GBP" })).append('<span class="icon icon-close removeGiftcard js-gift-card-remove js-gc-remove-amount-' + i + '"></span>');

$('.removeGiftcard').click(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Comment: Please see my comment above